# poll vs. epoll insight

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Are there some simple rules of thumb when to use `poll` vs. `epoll` in a low-latency environment? `epoll` should have higher overhead if only few of file-descriptors is monitored. Please, give some insight, answers "check it yourself" put elsewhere.

Comment: Personal anecdote: my results testing epoll vs. poll in a single process (no threads, no forks) asynchronous http server (ie, short connection times, <1000 concurrent sockets, giving ~10000 requests/sec) was that the difference between the two is negligible.  See my comment to plaes's answer for why.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow unfortunately closes questions such as these, where we ask for human expertise to tell us differences on `select` vs `poll` vs `epoll`, I have found the Bing AI GPT-4 to be a great resource instead. See my conversation here: [in multiplexed software development using Linux sockets, explain the differences and pros and cons of select vs poll vs epoll, and the evolution of each.](https://sl.bing.net/bVWkndUJni0). Among other things, it tells me that `epoll` uses red black binary search trees to be really efficient in scanning available file descriptors (FDs).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Always use `poll` unless all of the following are satisfied:

1. You can ensure you're on a (Linux) system that has `epoll` or you provide a fallback for systems that don't.
2. You have a **huge** number of file descriptors active (at least 1000-10000).
3. The set of file descriptors you're working with is stable over a long time period (adding/removing file descriptors from the `epoll` list is just as expensive as a `poll` operation, since it requires entering/leaving kernelspace).

Answer (score 21):

First of all, `poll(2)` is only level-triggered, but `epoll(4)` can be used as either edge- or level-triggered interface.

Now complexity: `poll` complexity regarding number of watched descriptors (fds) is O(n) as it scans all the fds every time when a 'ready' event occurs, `epoll` is basically O(1) as it doesn't do the linear scan over all the watched descriptors.

In terms of portability - as `epoll` is Linux-specific I would suggest checking out [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and [libevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent) libraries.
Also, check out Dan Kegel's excellent writeup: "[The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#strategies)".

Comment: I believe the point about epoll and big O notation is *not about the internals of either function*, so it is incorrect to say that "poll scans all the descriptors whereas epoll does not". *Both of them potentially trigger on a single event*.  However, with poll, the user then has no choice but to iterate thru the entire list submitted to find the events, whereas with epoll you get a list returned containing only the actual events.  This means if the server is very busy, there is no advantage to epoll.  However, if you are maintaining a very large number of descriptors over a long time...

Comment: ...and most of them are idle most of the time, epoll will have an advantage if you have very rapid events involving only a few connections.  Ie, the O(whatever) is about what's *possible* for the user implementation, not the actual behaviour of poll/epoll.

Comment: The most important point: *poll complexity regarding number of watched descriptors (fds) is O(n) as it scans all the fds every time when a 'ready' event occurs, epoll is basically O(1) as it doesn't do the linear scan over all the watched descriptors.*. So `epoll` scales better than `poll()`

Comment: From my test, poll is not O(N). If any descriptor match the event, it returns immediately. It's a worst case O(N).

Comment: While with epoll, you set the maximum number of event you are waiting for so it's O(m) with m < N in the worst case.

Answer (score 6):

`epoll(7)` summarizes it succinctly: `epoll` "scales well to large numbers of watched file descriptors." However, `poll` is a POSIX standard interface, so use that when portability is required.

Comment: Yes, it scales, but if the number of fds is small, `poll` should be faster.

Comment: @James: I really would like to see some benchmarks about this. From personal experience I would say that given you do something as a reaction on the event, there is no much difference. Given that you have to maintain the poll vector yourself, I would even guess that epoll is faster.The important difference is, as stated in this answer, that poll is POSIX and thus more portable. epoll has also the advantage of offering a few more features.